# Oracle trigger sequence and lpad

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequence

im trying to insert in my db a 4 charactes password. It is generated by a sequence... the problem im having is that i cant find a way to make that happend. I just find out about triggers, i  know the answer to my problem might be there and this is what i have till now :S

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PASSWORD 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF PASSWORD ON USER
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
     SELECT SEQ_PASSWORD.NEXTVAL
     INTO new.PASSWORD := LPAD(:new.PASSWORD,4,'0');
     FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Im new with all these database stuff! plz help! and sorry for my english btw! i know its awful!

Comment: what do you want to do with the generated value ?

Comment: Stored into the password column in the table USER

Comment: Don't store passwords... http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/

Comment: Also, if you want to generate passwords, use something like `DBMS_RANDOM.string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd password rules as it'd be relatively easy to guess a new user's... but you can do this:

```
 SELECT LPAD(SEQ_PASSWORD.NEXTVAL, 4, '0')
 INTO :new.PASSWORD
 FROM DUAL;
```

Or from 11g:

```
:new.PASSWORD := LPAD(SEQ_PASSWORD.NEXTVAL, 4, '0');
```

As an alternative to `LPAD` you could also use `TO_CHAR`:

```
:new.PASSWORD := TO_CHAR(SEQ_PASSWORD.NEXTVAL, 'FM0000');
```

Of course, all of these assume your `USER.PASSWORD` field is defined as `varchar2`, not as `number`.

You probably don't want the 'OF PASSWORD' clause though; that means the sequence will only be used to set the password if that field is set by the `insert` or `update` statement, which doesn't seem very intuitive; and resetting the password on update of anything seems unhelpful too.

Comment: Its just a first password that he should immediately change, but i dont want it the same everytime! Thx anyway for the answer ^^